# Javascript function stops working when if condition is added to a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i add the `if (hubsAndCenter[i])` line this function stops working (It becomes busy and the whole page stops responding) Can anybody see what i'm doing wrong?

```
function UpdateHubsAndCenter() {
    var hubsAndCenter = $("#HubsAndSiteSection :button");

    for (var i = 0; hubsAndCenter.length; i++) {
        if (hubsAndCenter[i])
            Update(hubsAndCenter[i].value, hubsAndCenter[i].value);

    }
}
```

Comment: `hubsAndCenter[i]` will *always* equate to `true`, so I'd imagine it's actually the `Update` function which is causing the blocking. Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to see where the problem is?

Comment: How does the `update()` look like?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sometimes hubsAndCenter[i] can become null, i assumed this would avoid it

Comment: The problem is without the IF conditions, the function works fine, It does generate 'cannot read value of null' errors, but it works

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that's the case. It'd be interesting to see a complete example that does it.

Comment: The fact that it works without the if-statement indicates that `Update` modifies `hubsAndCenter` while the function is iterating over it, which is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you don't have any real halting condition, the loop will run as long as the jQuery collection isn't empty.

Instead of

```
for (var i = 0; hubsAndCenter.length; i++) {
```

you probably should have this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < hubsAndCenter.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Nice catch, completely missed that :)